# Python Django не видит базу данных

Tags: python, django, база-данных

Такая вот проблема. Есть база данных TinyDB, есть функция Django во views.py для обработки запросов на урл. В ней должна открываться база данных DBTemplates.json, которая представляет собой массив словарей. Но вместо ожидаемого массива словарей я получаю пустой массив. Уже не знаю в чем проблема, битый час сижу и не могу решить.

Вот обрабатывающая урл функция

```
def get_form(request):
    db = TinyDB('DBTemplates.json')
    templates = db.all()
    print(templates)

    post_form = dict(request.GET)
    for key in post_form:
        post_form[key] = post_form[key][0]
    post_form = validation(post_form)

    names = []
    #print('  POST_FORM:     ', post_form)
    #print('  DBALL:      ', dball)
    for template in templates:
        print('template=', template)
        if DictComp(template, post_form):
            names = names.append(template['name'])
    #print(names)

    if names:
        return HttpResponse(names)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(post_form))
```

[image: Вот что я получаю после, когда передаю post_запросы - пустой массив вместо базы данных]

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь, возможно не тот файл открывается.

Comment: А лучше прикрепи еще структуру проекта